# Integrate Google checkout with Gravity Forms

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've created a multi step form using [gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) that I want to integrate Google checkout with.

I have the following steps:

1. Submit user details.
2. Add media.
3. Payment (this is where the Google checkout step would go).
4. Thank you.

As far as I can see Gravity forms uses jQuery to show/hide each step so on step 3 is it possible to insert a Google buynow button (that has a set price) using jQuery?

It doesn't matter if it means the client needs to manually check if the submission is paid for (i.e check the submission against the payment).

All I want to happen is the user goes through steps 1 & 2, pays at step 3 and comes back to the thank you page

Gravity forms doesn't currently offer a Google Checkout add-on (it offers Paypal) but because the submission has a single price that doesn't change, I'm wondering if there's a way to incorporate it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have pagebreak element to have the 4 steps of forms. In the payment part (after the second pagebreak, you can use HTML element to add your Google Checkout button.

Comment: Yep exactly how I did but on clicking the buy now button it submitted the gravity form and went to the thank you page without going to Google checkout to pay for the item. That would be ideal if it did actually pay but it didn't.